# Delete duplicates from postgresql database where certain field is null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, sql-delete

Consider following table:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  |     info     |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | Chris | NULL         |
|  2 | Den   | some info    |
|  3 | Bob   | another info |
|  4 | Bob   | NULL         |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

I want to delete all duplicates in field `name` but only those where `info` is `NULL`. For this example I'd like to delete only last Bob (id = 4).

Seems like I can select them with:

```
select name from mytable where info is null group by name having count(*) > 1;
```

But I can't check it's all right cause adding fields throws me an error:

```
select id, name from mytable where info is null group by name having count(*) > 1;
```

> ERROR:  column "mytable.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select id, name from
>   mytable where info is null group ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
delete from mytable 
where info is null
and exists (select *
            from mytable t2 
            where t2.name = mytable.name
              and t2.info is not null)
```